# Dependency Injection: Is there any such thing as lazy parameter passing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

DISCLAIMER: This is a general question about Dependency Injection without having to do with any specific product/project/DI-Solution. This question in no way is asking to compare features between DI solutions.

I am using DI in ASP.NET MVC 5 Project using `SimpleWebInjector`. Everything works cool as can be, my controllers have ctors that have parameters which have values injected properly, those dependencies have their own ctors that are getting params injected fine.

Now here is the peculiar scenario: One of the dependencies have a ctor parameter that can only be injected with a value provided to all Actions of my controller. How can I accomplish that? Is that even possible with DI?

Comment: What is this dependency ? are you trying to inject your DBContext into your MVC controller ? please elaborate the context here.

Comment: If the value is provided to an action, that means that it is _runtime data_. Runtime data should not be injected in to the constructor of your components. This is an anti-pattern, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99).

Comment: @Steven Post that as an answer. That link was a good read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> One of the dependencies have a ctor parameter that can only be injected with a value provided to all Actions of my controller.

If the value is provided to an action, that means that it is *runtime data*. Runtime data should not be injected in to the constructor of your components. This is an anti-pattern, as explained [here](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). In short, the article can be summarizd as:

> **Don't inject runtime data into application components during construction; it causes ambiguity, complicates the composition root with an extra responsibility and makes it extraordinarily hard to verify the correctness of your DI configuration. My advice is to let runtime data flow through the method calls of constructed object graphs.**

The article gives 2 general solutions:

> 1. **pass runtime data through method calls of the API or**
> 2. **retrieve runtime data from specific abstractions that allow resolving runtime data.**

Answer (score 0):

See how Castle Windsor, my favorite DI container, provides what you need.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IDBContext>().ImplementedBy<CustomDBContext>()
             .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", connectionString))
    );
```